# Docker Spawn a shell as a user instead of root

Tags: docker, containers, root

Usually when I develop application using docker container as my development test base I need in order to run manually composer, phpunit, npm, bower and various development scrips in it a shell via the following command:

```
docker exec -ti /bin/sh
```

But when the shell is spawned, is spawned with root permissions. What I want to achieve is to spawn a shell without root permissions but with a specified user one.

How I can do that?

In my case my `Dockerfile` has the following entries:

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm-alpine

ARG UID="1000"
ARG GID="1000"

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
COPY ./fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf


RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    addgroup -g ${GID} developer &&\
    adduser -D -H -S -s /bin/false -G developer -u ${UID} developer


ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And I mount a directory of my projject I develop from the host into `/var/www/html` and preserving the user permissions, so I just need the following `docker-compose.yml` in order to build it:

```
version: '2'
services:

 php_dev:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
   args:
     XDEBUG_HOST: 172.17.0.1
     XDEBUG_PORT: 9021
     UID: 1000
     GID: 1000
  image: pcmagas/php_dev
  links:
    - somedb
  volumes:
    - "$SRC_PATH:/var/www/html:Z"
```

Sop by setting the `UID` and `GID` into my host's user id and group id and with the following config form fpm:

```
[global]
daemonize = no

[www]
listen = 9000
user = developer
group = developer
```

I manage to run any changes to my code without worring about mysterious changes to user wonerships. But I want to be able to spawn a shell inside the running `php_dev` container as the developer user so any future tool such as `composer` or `npm` will run with the appropriate user permissions.

Of cource I guess same principles will apply into other languages as well for examples for python the `pip`

Comment: have you tried to add this line before your entrypoint ? `USER developer`

Comment: Why can't you just run `composer` or `npm` as another user then? `su` command is quite easy to run.

Comment: @Mike It is more convenient to run shell directly as user.

Comment: @Mostafa Hussein your solution seems to work.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas I have submitted the full answer with more explanation that you may need

Comment: Sounds like a fools errand. A lot of hacks just to avoid single `su - www-data`. Don't get me wrong, I use Docker extensively in a lot of projects (both in production and in development) and this works great.

Comment: If I do that it may mess my permissions on my project folder during development that's why I want to avoid it and use my own mapped user with hardcoded user is and group id where I manually set to my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need to run the container as a non-root user you have to add the following line to your `Dockerfile`:

```
USER developer
```

Note that in order to mount a directory through `docker-compose.yml` you have to change the permission of that directory before running `docker-compose up` by executing the following command

```
chown UID:GID /path/to/folder/on/host
```

`UID` and `GID` should match the `UID` and `GID` of the user's container.
This will make the user able to read and write to the mounted volume without any issues

Read more about [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) directive

Comment: Well I use the same user id and group is from the host that's why I pass them as build arguments in order to have a `mapped` user inside my container same as the one that runs outside too ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the end putting the line:

```
USER developer
```

Really works when you spawn a shell via the:

```
docker exec -ti /bin/sh
```