# How to change root shell in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker

I am writing a Dockerfile to customize the parrotsec/security container to better suit my preferences, and I'd want zsh as the default shell of root. I tried using

```
RUN chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

as well as

```
RUN usermod --shell /usr/bin/zsh root
```

but after building the image and running it the shell for the root user remains bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll need to add an `ENTRYPOINT` to your Dockerfile.  If you run a `docker inspect <image>` you'll see an Entrypoint entry in the output.

See [Docker Spawn a shell as a user instead of root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018143/docker-spawn-a-shell-as-a-user-instead-of-root) which seems pretty closely related to your situation.

Comment: Yes, it worked by adding ```ENTRYPOINT ["zsh"]```